# Check if list of objects contains a specific value

Tags: c#, list, object, contains

I am trying to figure out, if possible, how to check if a object contains a specific value.

My contentList of object is as follows:

```
[{
    "TypeId": 1,
    "Content": "Some content here"
},
{
    "TypeId": 2,
    "Content": "Some new content here"
},
{
    "TypeId": 4,
    "Content": "Some other content here"
}]
```

Now, what I would like to be able to do, is search something like this:

```
if(commentsList.Contains(4))
```

I would like to check if the commentsList has an object with the TypeId 4.

Can this be done?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: commentsList.Select(x = > x.TypeId).Contains(4) ? Or as Jerodev's answer says `commentsList.Any(x => x.TypeId ?? 4)`

Comment: Looking at your data, a `Dictionary` keyed by `TypeId` might be a better container than a list, and you could do `dic.ContainsKey(4)` for optimal retrieval.

Comment: @vc74 but then you would'nt you need to split the Object into two different objects one of Type "TypeId" and the other of Type "Content"?

Comment: @MindSwipe No, it would be a `Dictionary<int, Content>`

Comment: @vc74 you could do that. But right now you have `List<TypeContent>` which you'd need to tear apart. I see your point with the dictionary, but the dictionary only makes sense if you have the, what seems to be JSON, serialized data and need to de-serialize it an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) to check if there is an element in the list that satisfies the requirement.

```
commentsList.Any(x => x.TypeId == 4)
```

Comment: There is a plethora of ways of doing this, using `Any` is certainly one of the cleanest ways of doing it